# Proving ineqalities for the similarity dimension

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

> a. Let $K$ be the attractor of the IFS $\{f_1,\dots f_n\}$ which satisfies SSC (i.e $f_i(K)\cap f_j(K)=\emptyset\forall i\neq j$) where for all $i, c_i$ such that $ 1\le i\le n, \space 0<c_i<1$ we have $$|f(y)-f(x)|\le c_i|y-x|$$Prove that $\dim_HK\le s$ s.t $\sum_i c_i^s=1$.
>
> b. Let $H$ be attractor for this IFS such that $$|f(y)-f(x)|\ge c_i|y-x|$$ Prove that now $\dim_HH\ge s$

First using the given inequalities I thought that fixing $\alpha>0$ $$\mathscr{H}^\alpha(f_j(K))\le c_j^\alpha\mathscr{H}^\alpha(K)$$ and since $\mathscr{H}^\alpha(K)=\sum_{j=1}^\ell\mathscr{H}^\alpha(f_j(K))$ it follows that $\sum c_j^\alpha\ge 1$ and doing the same for (b), fixing $\beta$ we get $\sum_ic_j^\beta\le 1$. How in each part of the question we get the inverse inequality?

**EDIT:** The question is defined on closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ so I thought taking $\mu=\mathscr{L}^d$ but I cannot applicate it in (b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument does not work if the $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is $0$ or $\infty$, which it is for typical $\alpha$.

For part (a), if $(U_j)_{j}$ is any covering of $K$ with finitely many bounded sets, applying the IFS to it you get a new finite covering $(f_i(U_j))_{i,j}$ of $K$, and (using $|U|$ for the diameter of $U$)
$$
\sum_{i,j} |f_i(U_j)|^s \le \sum_{i,j} c_i^s |U_j|^s = \sum_j |U_j|^s.
$$
So if you repeatedly apply the IFS to any initial finite covering, the sums of the $s$-th powers of the diameters stay bounded, and the maximum diameter of the covering goes to $0$, which implies that the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of $K$ is finite, so the Hausdorff dimension is at most $s$.

The standard proof for part (b) uses the mass distribution principle, where you use the IFS to define a self-similar measure and show that it satisfies an inequality like $\mu(B_r(x)) \le C r^s$, where $B_r(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. The details are a little more involved than the proof of (a). (However, that proof works under slightly weaker separation conditions, namely the open set condition. Maybe with the strong separation you are assuming there might be a shorter less technical proof.)

A good reference for all of this is Falconer's book on Fractal Geometry.

Comment: Thanks. about b: You mean probability measure? How will proving this inequality helps?

Comment: Probability measure, yes. It helps because if $(U_j)$ is any covering of $K$, then you get $1 = \mu(K) \le \sum_j \mu(U_j) \le C \sum_j |U_j|^s$, i.e., $\sum_j |U_j|^s \ge C^{-1}$.

Comment: The same $C$ as in the inequality for the measure. (Just in case it was not clear, that inequality has to hold for all balls, with $C$ independent of $x$ and $r$.)

Comment: Can you explicit way to build such $\mu$?

Comment: The measure of a cylinder set $K_{i_1, \ldots, i_m}=f_{i_1} \circ \cdots \circ f_{i_m}(K)$ is defined as $(c_{i_1} \cdots c_{i_m})^s$. You have to show that this uniquely defines a measure and that it satisfies this inequality which are both not too hard.

Comment: I cannot see why your measure satisfies the inequality above or how that follows from the given inequality in (b).

Comment: Can you show full solution for (b) please?

Comment: The very rough idea for the estimate is that the inequality gives that $|K_{i_1,\ldots,i_m}| \ge |K| c_{i_1} \cdots c_{i_m}$, so you have this inequality for cylinder sets, and any ball is contained in a cylinder set of comparable diameter. Did you try to look it up in Falconer? (Or really in any other serious book about fractal geometry, it is in all of them.)